# Call function after another function completes

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, promise

I am trying to use a promise to ensure one function, "submit()" is called after the another function, "save()" has been completed. I haven't used promises in a long while and I'm confused on the syntax. I also tried using async and await but to no avail.

```
public globalFunction() {
//call save() first, wait until fully completed and then call submit()
    this.save().then(() => {
        this.submit(approver);
    })

    //this.save().then(res => this.submit(approver));
}

save() {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {

    this.service.save(this.item.id, updatedItemList).pipe(
      first(),
      catchError((err) => {
        this.toastService.show(`Save failed`, { type: "error" });
        return null;
      })
    ).subscribe((success: boolean) => {
        this.loadItemss().then(() => {
        this.uploadDocs();
      });
      this.toastService.show("Successfully saved", { type: "success" });
    });


    resolve();
  });
}

private submit(approver: Lookup): void {
    this.service.submit(this.item.id, approver).pipe(
      first(),
      catchError((error) => {
        this.toastService.show(`Submit failed`, { type: 'error' });
        return null;
      })
    ).subscribe((success: boolean) => {
      this.toastService.show(`Successfully submitted`, { type: 'success' })
    });
}
```

Comment: What is the problem, what does not work? Be a bit more specific please.

Comment: You're fulfilling the promise with the value `undefined` **immediately** by calling it at the top level of your promise executor function (the function you pass into `new Promise`). Instead, move the call to `resolve` into the callback where you're showing the success message (and add a call to `reject` in the callback where you're showing the failure), so you don't fulfill or reject the promise until the save is complete.

Comment: There's bound to be a good dupetarget for this.

Comment: Since you use rxjs, I'd suggest you use that to the largest extent possible to achieve asynchronous behavior. So instead of subscribing in save(), and then mergeMap or something into loadItemss and then mergeMap into uploadDocs (both of which should also be made into observables). Then the calling function (globalFunction in this case) subscribes to the observable created by save()

Comment: Thanks for this! I just moved the resolve() - been on a task for a while and has lost all vision